# Unit test for variables using pytest

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a very basic question. Suppose i have a function:

```
def func(a,b):
    a=a*2
    b=b*3
```

Now i want to test for values of a and b only, how can this be accomplished

I tried using mock.patch and call_args_list and I guess that should somehow get the work done but I am all mixed up in the syntax for the same.

Thank you!

Comment: you can use assert function from pytest

Comment: @vmicrobio i am able to use the assert function but that i am only able to use on the return value and not on a and b. Pls read the full question

Comment: you will not be able to test those variables easily (without some crazy introspection hack) as they exist only within the functions local scope.

Answer (score -1):

You can test the values of a and b using pytest framework such as:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,b,expected_a,expected_b", [(2, 3, 4, 9)])
def test_func(a,b,expected_a,expected_b):
    func(a,b)
    assert a == expected_a
    assert b == expected_b
```

`@pytest.mark.parametrize` is used to define potential values of a and b that to be tested, as well as the expected values of a and b after calling the `func()` function.

`Assert` statement is then used to check whether the actual values of a and b match the expected values, if no match then the test will fail.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tested the same, but when i am running the code the test is failing as its showing "assert 2==4". I guess the value of a is not getting updated.